Can a strong stack exchange profile enhance cv for phd ammission?
I am from Italy and I am completing a physics master's degree. It's common in my country having a large proportion of graduates graduating with laude and I want my cv to stand out.
Can a strong physics stack exchange profile help me?
I am also curious about your personal experiences in fields outside of physics in this regard.

This seems to be just opinion based. I think it would be far down the list of things considered important. You probably have more important things to do than spend as much time here as I do (retired).

https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4873/chemistry-se-on-your-cv-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9-other-professional-avenues is also relevant.
